# Can't curently log in as user in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login, users

After the installation of Ubuntu 12.04 was finished, I was told to reboot my system.  When it came backup, and after I logged in on the login screen, nothing happens, like its stuck there. I waited for a long time, and I can't login onto my machine.  why? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did your mouse cursor move after you typed your login password? In my case, the mouse cursor appeared but I couldn't move it at all. It was totally frozen up. I solved this issue just by reinstalling GRUB. If your situation is similar, this should help.

1. Power off your computer.
2. Press power button to boot up.
3. Hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> to get into GRUB menu.
4. Choose "Recovery mode" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. You may have to login with your regular user name.
6. Run these commands:

   `sudo apt-get purge grub-common` (This will delete your grub)
   `sudo apt-get install grub-common grub2` (Reinstall grub)
   `sudo update-grub` (**this is important**)
   `sudo init 6` (This will reboot your laptop)

**Reference:** [Ubuntu stuck at desktop w/ frozen mouse after apt upgrade](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ubuntu-stuck-at-desktop-w-frozen-mouse-after-apt-upgrade-872707/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Thin Clients on Ubuntu 12.04 server. What I did was Hit **Preferences** on the bottom left of the login screen and change the desktop to **2D**. You may have to try another desktop. What I feel is that there might be an incomplete installation of drivers during installing the desktop for Ubuntu. Try reinstalling the desktop or use the others available.

Comment: The likelihood of corruption during install is extraordinarily low.  What're you basing that on?  It's more likely their hardware is not capable of handling the 3d unity.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean corruption in Ubuntu. Let me rephrase that. I think it's incomplete (missing) installation of display drivers during installation. The installation must be using the basic driver for the display card.